# Unresolved Segmentation fault while trying to simplify directory path using stacks

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stack

I was trying to resolve my segmentation fault when i was using stacks to simplify my directory path. But I can't seem to find anything that would cause the issue. Am I missing something?

```cpp
string Solution::simplifyPath(string A) {
    string a="";
    stack<char> one;
    stack<char> res;
    for(int i=0; i<A.length();i++){
        one.push(A[i]);
    }
    one.pop();
    while(one.top()!='/'){
        res.push(one.top());
        one.pop();
        }
    res.push('/');
    while(res.top()!=NULL){
        a+=res.top();
        res.pop();
    }
    return a;
}
```

```
Error message:

Runtime Error. Your submission stopped because of a runtime error. ex: division by zero, array index out of bounds, uncaught exception You can try testing your code with custom input and try putting debug statements in your code.

Segmentation fault.
```

Comment: Did you run it in the debugger?

Comment: What happens to `while(one.top()!='/')` if `one` doesn't have a `'/'` in it?

Comment: See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @Riataro In my opinion the function does not make sense.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(res.top()!=NULL)
```

`std::stack::top()` does not return NULL when the stack is empty. It causes undefined behaviour instead.

Comment: Thank you. I completely overlooked that.

Comment: @Riataro the point is that you should have found it using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the stack is not empty before using `stack::top()` or `stack::pop()`.

`while(!one.empty() && one.top()!='/')`